# Map both elements from 2d Array Javascript at the same time

Tags: javascript

My `data` array is a 2d array and each inner array holds data in the form `[date, color]`. I am trying to graph the dates and the colors and to do this I am trying to map the elements in the inner array. However, my current map function does not work when I try mapping two elements at once. How can I fix this?

```
shapes: data.map((date, type_color) => ({
                      
                        x0: date,
                        y0: 0,
                        x1: date,
                        y1: 1,
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        line: {
                            color: type_color,
                            width: 3,
                            dash: 'dot'
                        }
                    }))
```

Comment: show an example of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to be using destructuring, but you aren't; you're just accepting two separate parameters in your `map` callback. When you do that, the first will be the `[date, color]` array (each element from the `data` array); the second will be the index of the element in `data`.

To use parameter destructuring, you'd use `[date, type_color]` in the parameter list:

```
shapes: data.map(([date, type_color]) => ({
//                ^                ^
    x0: date,
    y0: 0,
    x1: date,
    y1: 1,
    opacity: 0.8,
    line: {
        color: type_color,
        width: 3,
        dash: 'dot'
    }
}))
```

That applies `[date, type_color]` destructuring to the first parameter.

```js
const data = [
    ["date1", "color1"],
    ["date2", "color2"],
    ["date3", "color3"],
];

const result = {
    shapes: data.map(([date, type_color]) => ({
    //                ^                ^
        x0: date,
        y0: 0,
        x1: date,
        y1: 1,
        opacity: 0.8,
        line: {
            color: type_color,
            width: 3,
            dash: 'dot'
        }
    }))
};
console.log(result.shapes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```